# Camera, CameraOptions doesn't work in my mobile application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am developing a mobile application, and i want to open the gallery for select a picture, but when the button is clicked the application does not anything, not even throw an error, this is my code:

```
photos: any = '';
base64Image = '';

async agregarImg() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
    header: 'Seleccionar medio',
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Cámara',
      icon: 'camera',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(CameraSource.Camera, false)
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Galería',
      icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'ios-images-outline' : 'images-outline',
      handler: () => {
        this.openGallery();
      }
    }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

openGallery() {

    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true,
      allowEdit: false,
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
      this.photos.reverse();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}
```

I read about the problem, probably this happens for the plugin, this does not work perfectly on Android.
I use this plugin: import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

Comment: Do you put console.log statements in your code to see where it's breaking down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change my old code to this new one:

```
async agregarImg() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
    header: 'Seleccionar medio',
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Cámara',
      icon: 'camera',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(CameraSource.Camera, false, 1)
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Galería',
      icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'ios-images-outline' : 'images-outline',
      handler: () => {
        this.takePicture(CameraSource.Photos, false, 2)
      }
    }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

async takePicture(source: CameraSource, editable: boolean, flag: number) {
    if(flag === 1) {
      this.imgPerfilCamera = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 50,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
        saveToGallery: false,
        allowEditing: editable,
        source,
      });
    } else {
      this.imgPerfilCamera = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 50,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
        saveToGallery: false,
        allowEditing: editable,
        source: CameraSource.Photos
      });
    }
  }
```

with this plugin

```
import { CameraPhoto, CameraResultType, CameraSource, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
```

Add a new file on my project root called "patch-camera.js" with this code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const f =
  "node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/plugin/Camera.java";

fs.readFile(f, "utf8", function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(
    "String filename = contentUri.getLastPathSegment()",
    'String filename = "file"'
  );

  fs.writeFile(f, result, "utf8", function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

And add the postinstall script in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node patch-camera.js"
```

This code works.

Answer (score 0):

Taking from [the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera), I would recommend the following changes

```
openGallery() {
   const options: CameraOptions = {
     ...
     destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType. FILE_URI,
     pictureSourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
     ...
```

Comment: I use sourceType instead pictureSourceType, because when i put pictureSourceType throw me an error "Object literal may only specify know properties", i put that code line but it still doesn't work